# mat-table action does not fire when row clicked

Tags: typescript, angular5

I'm fairly new to angular, and trying to make use of some of the functionality of mat tables.  While I have most of what I need working done, I am unable to get any action to fire when I click a row.  My test for this functionality is to delete the row clicked.  What I really want is to display another component, but I haven't started on that so deleting provides a clear signal that the on click is firing for the right row.

The table is as follows:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="title">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Part Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let part"> {{ part.title }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="partNumber">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Part Number</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let part"> {{ part.partNumber }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Description</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let part"> {{ part.description }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="leadTime">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Lead Time</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let part"> {{ part.leadTime }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Weight</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let part"> {{ part.weight }}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" click="displayDetail(row._id)"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

Which fires the following event in my component file:

```
partList: Array<Part> = new Array<Part>();
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.partList);

displayDetail(i) {
   this.partList.splice(i, 1);
}
```

I've messed around with a lot of pieces and done just about everything I can think of, but I feel like my inexperience with angular is causing me to overlook something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this in case anyone else has a similar issue.

I had a few problems with the code, but this is the now-working code block:

```
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" 
     (click)="displayDetail(row.partNumber)"></mat-row>
```

This identifies a few issues.  click should have been wrapped in parenthesis (I am not certain this was an issue, but it was part of the steps that caused it to work).

The real issue is the row object.  The example I was sourcing from had an _id field in its mat column set.  This row object is not some mat-specific thing, but just an object that represents the data from your datasource (the mistake in understanding that I had was that it was something specific to the mat table).  As such, it only has the rows/data that you give it from the datasource.  If my data had an id field in it, I could call it by id.  As it does not, I was not getting valid information.

I changed it to return a unique identifier in the data that I need to pass to the next component.  And all was good.